# How to align the elements using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox. I've created a poll and I have problems with aligning the elements, see picture below. This is my HTMl:

```css
.d-table {
  display: table!important;
}

.d-table-row {
  display: table-row !important;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display: table-cell!important;
}

.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.align-middle>div {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex!important;
}

.RowMargin {
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.flex-column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse!important;
}

.CheckboxWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  border: 1px solid #343c49;
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.CheckboxWrap+div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It would be ideal if all the elements were equally distributed, for now my last item is not equal as other and this is a main problem. I would ask you to look at the picture so you can see what it is all about. If you have any idea how to solve this, I would be very grateful :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To begin with your issue is the text. See my example below**

```css
.d-table {
  display: table!important;
}

.d-table-row {
  display: table-row !important;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display: table-cell!important;
}

.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.align-middle>div {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex!important;
}

.RowMargin {
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.flex-column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse!important;
}

.CheckboxWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  border: 1px solid #343c49;
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.CheckboxWrap+div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">7</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">8</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">9</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">11</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">12</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `I can not estimate` bit is making the div longer because there is no fixed div size. This is the brilliance but also the downfall of flex.

A solution could be adding a fixed size to your `.RowMargin` like so:

```
.RowMargin {
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Or you could move away from flex and look at grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color:blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">1</div>
  <div class="box b">2</div>
  <div class="box c">3</div>
  <div class="box d">4</div>
  <div class="box e">5</div>
  <div class="box f">6</div>
  <div class="box d">7</div>
  <div class="box e">8</div>
  <div class="box f">9</div>
  <div class="box d">10</div>
  <div class="box e">11</div>
  <div class="box f">12</div>
</div>
```

The layout of the grid is provided by this line: `grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;` There are 6 `10%` so the 6 boxes are laid out in a 6 column with a width of 10%.

Gird is simple and very effective. However both have browser restrictions.
See here

[css gird browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid) | [Flex browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

They can however both be used in conjunction with eachother :)

> Further reading

https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

http://flexboxgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
.RowMargin {
    min-width: 45px;
    margin-right:15px;;
}
```

`min-width` and `margin-right` to every element so it will distribute same `width`

```css
.d-table {
  display: table!important;
}

.d-table-row {
  display: table-row !important;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display: table-cell!important;
}

.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.align-middle>div {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex!important;
}

.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex!important;
}

.RowMargin {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-width: 45px;
}

.flex-column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse!important;
}

.CheckboxWrap {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  border: 1px solid #343c49;
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.CheckboxWrap+div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row ">
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">
      <div class="CheckboxWrap">
        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1">5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex RowMargin flex-column-reverse">

      <div class="CheckboxWrap">

        <input type="radio" name="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="text1"><span style="font-size:75%">I can not
                            <br>estimate </span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```